# Как удалить все что после "?" в String

Tags: java

Имеется ссылка вида `https://m.vc.com/id2436187?from=friends`. Как удалить `?from=friends`?

Comment: `str.replace("?from=friends'" "")`

Answer (score 3):

Возможно и так:

```
String link = "https://m.vc.com/id2436187?from=friends";
int lastIndex = link.indexOf("?");
String newString = lastIndex > 0 ? link.substring(0, lastIndex) : link ;
```

Answer (score 3):

у или так

```
String link = "https://m.vc.com/id2436187?from=friends";
String newString = link.split("?")[0];
```